# Update javascript variable using another variable value

Tags: javascript

I have a situation as follows.

```
var varable_1=10;
var variable_2=20;
.....
var variable_n=10000;
function update_varable(variable){
   ....some code.....
}
```

I need to update each of those variables  by calling update_variable('variable_1');update_variable('variable_2')....etc.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply use an array like `var variables = [10, 20, 30, /* , ... */ , 10000]`? Then you could just give `update_variable` the index `i` and use `variables[i]`.

Comment: Can you put more details in your question? As I understood, you're trying to loop through all the variables in a function?

Comment: sorry for the inclonvenience. actually i neeed to implement a function for updating different variables. For illustrating it i use variable_1, variable_2 etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the variables inside the function `update_variable` then you need to remove the quotes in your example. There is many ways to do it, I post a simple one. You can also pass more than one variable inside the function.

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/KMzRB/)**

```
var varable_1=10;
var variable_2=20;
var variable_n=10000;
function update_variable(x){
x = 300 //some new value
return x;
}
```

and the call:

```
variable_1 = update_variable(varable_1);
```

( your function name misses an "i" on some lines, it's "update_varable" )

```
                                                   ^  
                                               missing "i"
```

Comment: var is keyword. So no problem? Is it work as pass by reference?

Comment: @ManeeshMohanachandran, It's already corrected, var cannot be used as variable, of course. Thanks, got an early morning :)

Comment: @ManeeshMohanachandran, i added a live example also in my answer.

Comment: got the right answer. Thank you. 'i' missed when i typed it into the stack. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think array is more suitable for the task.

But you can use this code with eval function if your varaibles names are like var1, var2 .. varN:

```
    var var1 = 10;
    var var2 = 20;

    function update_var(variable) {
        return variable += 1;
    }

    function main() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            eval("var" + i + " = update_var(var" + i + ")");
            eval("console.log(var" + i + ");");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a string as argument for the update function, you can use `eval` inside of the function to get the real variable behind the string:

```
function update(varName) {
    eval(varName + " += 1;");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the facts here:

- Your variables have a pattern: variable_x so, for our algorithm it s just a string: 'variable_' + x
- All your variables will be attached to an object, wetter it is a declared object, or a global one, for example: a, myVars, or *window*
- Any object in javascript can be accessed using indexers, so myObject.myVar can be also written like myObject['myVar'].

Now let's see the algorithm:

```
function update(variable, value){
        window[variable] = value;
}
```

You can call it like you wanted:

```
update('variable_1', 450.25);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function update_varable(variable){
   variable += 10;

return variable;
}
```